# Large amount of objects upload and download from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I am quite new with .NET, C# and WCF and I am trying to create a service that will expose methods to allow upload and download of a large amount objects (array of objects).  I have seen a lot of posts regarding large file transfers in WCF, but I can't seem to find anything that focuses on just uploading and downloading large amounts of serializable objects.

I have been able to "hack up" the web.config file for the allowed bytes and timeout limit etc, but I am wondering if there are actually better ways to configure the `WCF` for better speed and memory usage to allow for such transmission. Because I have configured the web.settings based on my testing results (if time out/byte limit exceeded, increase the limit with some crazy large numbers etc) I doubt my configuration is making sense at all.

Second, I have seen some implementation options like having binding `TransferMode = Streaming or MTOM`, yet I don't know if they will apply to my scenario at all.  Can someone please point me to the correct direction?

Sorry I might not have constructed my question well enough, but ideas will be much appreciated.

Below is my web.config settings:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="409600000" executionTimeout="360000"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"  />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHTTP" closeTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
          sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferSize="655360000" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000"
          messageEncoding="Text" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WebService.WebService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="BasicEndPoint" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHTTP" name="BasicHTTP" contract="WebService.IWebService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BasicEndPoint">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536000" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? Are you able to transfer large object?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry about being too vague, cause I am quite lost after all the struggle to make it work.  I have been able to send through 73000 (200 * 365 days) of data objects to the WCF, but only if i keep increasing the limits etc..  I am wondering if there are better ways to do this?  streaming?  MTOM?  or if i should use other mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use Stream mode only for tasks like video/audio streaming or similar, when you really have stream on host and you really need receive stream on client. 
For any other tasks i would use Buffer mode because it is really easier to use and becase many useful wcf features rely on buffering. Using streaming with enabled SOAP message-level security (for example), can probably eliminate speed benefits of streaming mode (if you ever had some).

In your case i would recommend you to perform some workaround. Check these steps:

- Try to use compression. It can greatly improve speed and resource usage, but it can not guarantee that your amount of data always will be the same. Who knows if your array will be 100x larger next year? So you may return to this point one year later.
- Replace your method returning one giant array with method returning only one element or a small range of them. Then replace one *GetAllStuff()* method call with one call of *GetItemsCountForDownload()* and appropriate number of calls of *GetElementAtIndex(int index)* (or *GetElementsRange(int startIndex,int endIndex)*). Anyway, at this poin you will have to find some balance between message size (for each call) and number of calls performed.
- If your data can not be easily splitted into small equal parts (e.g. first element of array is 10kb, second is 15 kb and third is 338mb), then try to combine both methods together: serialize your array to disk, compress it whith splittig to some number of parts of acceptable size and then trasfer them one after another.
- Try to make parameters of your algorithm ajustable. Put them in your config file, so it will be possible to tune splitting process and compression level on every deployment machine according to avaliable resources.
- Another benefit of splitting data and downloading chunk by chunk easiness to build some error-handling layer. If connection is unstable and transfer fails for some reason you can try to redownload only one chuk instead of all the data.

**Some tips on architecture**

- Find appropriate crossplatform compression algorithm. Definitely you can find one that meets your needs. Look at [BZip2 for C# <-> Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474294/880156) and [GZip for C# <-> Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5178174/880156).
- Try to make your architecture clear enough for other programmers. You can make different methods for compressed data transfer and for uncopressed (*GetElementsRange*, *GetElementsRangeGZip*, *GetElementsRangeBZip2*). Or you can make one method with compression type paramether (*GetElementsRange(int startIndex,int endIndex,string compressionType*). Anyway, other programmer must be able understand what data he is receiving and how to control compression mode.
- You can move data splitting parameter from config file to method definition, so client will be able to define it by himself.
- You can go further and implement two step architecture. Step one: remote client defines parameters of request (all of them, including compression mode, splitting mode and all other). Step two: receiving data. How about tokens? Methods should look like:

  ```
  string GetTokenForDataRequest(string compressionMode, int maxChunkSize); //additional parameters like dates range, account number an other are defined in this method only
  int GetChunkCount(string token);
  byte[] GetDataChunkAtIndex(string token, int index);
  ```

Here *compressionMode*  may be "None","BZip2" or "GZip"; If *maxChunkSize* is 0 then disable splitting (all data will be sent in one chunk), else split data in chunks with size equal to *maxChunkSize* (the last one will be smaller than other). So approximate scenario would be like:

1. Remote client sends a data request with desired parameters.
2. You generate session id (a token), save parameters for this session and prepare data according to parameters. "Prepare data" means loading data according to request, creating temp folder, serializind data, creating chunk files and persisting paths for further usage.
3. Client recieves a token, that is used for all other methods for retrieving data.
4. Every time remote client request data chunk throu your methods you will know where it stored on hard disk, how many chunks left and so on - thanks to provided token and persisted info.
5. You can easily handle simultaneous data transfer session with several clients at one time with no efforts (just make shure you store data chunks in different temp files and folders)
6. Client is able to redownload any chunk and you will not have to load data from database (or wherever it comes from).
7. When transfer is complete, you can wipe temp data and free some resources.

Do not look at this as at only possible solution. Just google around a little bit and you will find your very own way to solve your task!

Comment: Compression - i will have to take a look and get myself familiar with it first, just wondering it this will place any impact for users that are not C# clients.  Methods - i am actually considering putting in limits - say only max 10000 allowed for upload or download at 1 request, but wondering if i can allow users to not have such restriction.  Last but not least, can you point me to the right direction to learn how to put in compression or the splitting process?  Thank you so so so much once again.

Comment: Thank you so so much for such a detail answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) message transfer, but it has some limitations.
If the streaming isn't suitable for you, you can implement paging of data (or try existing implementations, like in [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473424.aspx)).

Comment: WCF data services seems very useful, i will try to get familiar with it first.  Thank you Dennis